# Align an image in the middle

Tags: css, reactjs

Im trying to align the image in the middle of the page, but its failing to do that. Currently, it's positioned on the very left side of `container`. React's render code:

```
return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div id="logo">
                        <img src={require('../../images/vidn_logo.png')} />
                    </div>
                    {heading}
                    <form className="form-signin" onSubmit={this.formSubmit}>
                        <input onChange={this.setEmail} type="email" className="form-control"
                               autoComplete="email" placeholder="Email" required></input>
                        <input onChange={this.setPass} type="password" className="form-control"
                               autoComplete="new-password" placeholder="Password" required></input>
                        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
                                type="submit" style={{marginTop: '20px'}}>Log In</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
        width: auto;
        padding: 60px 0 100px;
    }
#logo {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
        height: 30px;
    }
```

What should i add/edit in order the img was in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

try doing

```
<div className="logo-wrapper"><div id="logo>...</div></div>

.container {
   width: 100%;
}

.logo-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your logo has a set width and height, you could probably just do

```
#logo{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

provided that your image encompasses the entire logo container.
If your image's size is smaller than the #logo div, you can just add

```
#logo{
    text-align: center;
}
```

to center its contents horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

```
#logo {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: this is absolutely not an answer

Comment: Why not? Did you try? I tried and it works with this example of html in codepen.

Comment: I'm not saying that it doesn't work, I'm simply pointing out that you haven't explained to OP why you solve his problem

Comment: Do you think I must write a novel for explaining why this simple string is worked in this case? I'm sorry but your judgment is biased.

Comment: There are four answers here, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45679507/6331369) has the same code but he explains how it works...

Comment: But you don't know that my answer was several minutes ahead of others. You have come to this topic too late and see only hours. I repeat again you don't know all the truth and make a biased judgment.

Comment: Speed is not as important as quality.

Comment: What's wrong with the quality of my answer? Too short? It contains what to do & where to do. It's enough for solving the problem. Have you ever heard of Occam's razor?